# Reading references about the process of proving a theorem, or doing mathematics in general

Tags: reference-request

Doing mathematics is a very unique process, that puzzles non-mathematicians. All PhD students or professional mathematicians regularly hear things like "What? There are still theorems to prove? In 2015?" or "You're mathematician? So... what do you *exactly* do?".

I am looking about writings that describes the process, at the down-to-earth (dailylife of a mathematician) and emotionally level. Technical process, that is what is a proof or how one work comes to be published is interesting, but is not my main interest. *Birth of a theorem* by Cedric Villani, is a nice example.

**Could you advice me some other readings on that topic?**

More details about what I would like to read (though any suggestion is welcome):

1. I would prefer short stories or novellas rather than long novels. I found Villani 's point of view quite elitist, so I wish to hear about other part of the spectrum on how mathematicians think about their art.
2. It doesn't need to be a historical account about famous theorems, or stories by famous mathematicians. It doesn't matter if it is the story of a mathematical success or a failure.
3. It has to be a real story (since I am mostly interested on the emotional, intimate process), or at least a fictional story closely based on real elements (for example, a mathematician that changes elements of a real story to hide his identity).
4. Available in French, English or Spanish.

Comment: Do biographies count? If so, does the biography of a physicist count? Abraham Pais, a long time ago, wrote a biography of Einstein that contains a great deal of "intimate science" details, as I recall. The book is actually divided into two sections, one is the bio itself, the other is a bio of sorts of Einstein's work, so it's much more technical than the first section. Anyway, if interested, here's an Amazon link: [Subtle Is the Lord: The Science and the Life of Albert Einstein](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Subtle-Is-Lord-Science-Einstein/dp/0192806726).

Comment: @wltrup: I would prefer autobiographies, but biographies that details the intimate aspects are welcome. Theoretical physicists count.

Comment: Fair enough. Here's one I haven't read yet: Dirac's biography. [The Strangest Man: The hidden Life of Paul Dirac, Quantum Genius](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Strangest-Man-hidden-Quantum-Genius/dp/0571222862)